# How to inverse top and bottom ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to get 100 "above" the radius, if I consider that the radius comes from the center towards the circle.
A little example :

```
\documentclass[landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}     
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \a in {0,20,...,340}{%
    \draw (0,0)--(\a:4cm) node [pos=.75,above,sloped] {$\a$};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}      
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another example :

```
    \documentclass[landscape]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[color=blue] 
      \node (A) at (2,-4){A};
      \node (O) at (0,0){O};
      \node (B) at (-2,-4){B};   
    \draw[color=red] (O)  to node[sloped,above]{label} 
                             node[sloped,above,blue,rotate=180]{label} (A) ; 
    \draw[color=red] (O)  to node[sloped,above]{label}(B) ;
   %\draw[color=red] (B)  to node[sloped,above]{label}(O) ;   
    \end{tikzpicture}    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

In this example, I always thought that if  I reverse the nodes then I reverse the top and bottom but I was wrong.

A solution is to use a rotation but...it's not automatic.
 The only idea I had, is to use the rotation after testing the angle formed by the two points and the horizontal axe.

Comment: The key `allow upside down`?

Comment: +1 Fine ! I forgot this key :(  I think it's the solution perhaps Christophe you can put your comment in an answer

Comment: You can use `auto=right` (or `left`) to get consistent placement on one side of the line. This will cause issues with the placement though, since the right anchor of the node is then used.

Comment: I need to test the two propositions with concrete examples

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The key `allow upside down` might fit your needs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}     
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \a in {0,20,...,340}{%
    \draw (0,0) -- (\a:4cm) 
      node [pos=.75,above,sloped,allow upside down] {$\a$};}
\end{tikzpicture}      
\end{document}
```