# Circular sequence diagram (tikz?)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, circles

Apologies in advance for the slightly-crappy camera phone picture:

[image: circular sequence]

I'd like to include some figures like this in something I'm working on. I've just started learning tikz, which seems like it could be used to do something like this, but I'm not quite dextrous enough just yet.

The included picture has 16 cells, but I have another figure with 8 cells and a less important one with 27 cells, so if this can be done generally to make doing those easy as well, that'd be great.

Comment: some related posts: [question search for ring chart](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=ring+chart)

Comment: It would be nice to have certain cells filled with color.

Comment: You can check the examples of `chains` and `foreach` commands in the manual for a few examples similar to this one. Also you can check this one for the repetition task. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42261/how-to-inverse-top-and-bottom

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `CircularSequence` macro below takes three paramaters:

- The outer radius
- the inner radius
- the sequence to be applied

which should be able to create this image with any desired number of elements. Below are examples with 8 and 16 elements:

[image]

### References:

- [Macro to access a specific member of a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21559/macro-to-access-a-specific-member-of-a-list)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21559/macro-to-access-a-specific-member-of-a-list/21560#21560
\newcommand*\GetListMember[2]{\StrBetween[#2,\number\numexpr#2+1]{,#1,},,\par}%

\newlength{\MidRadius}
\newcommand*{\CircularSequence}[3]{%
    % #1 = outer circle radius
    % #2 = inner circle radius
    % #3 = seqeunce
    \StrCount{#3}{,}[\NumberOfElements]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\AngleSep}{360/(\NumberOfElements+1)}
    \pgfmathsetlength{\MidRadius}{(#1+#2)/2}
    \draw [red,  ultra thick] circle (#2);
    \draw [blue, ultra thick] circle (#1);
    \foreach [count = \Count] \Angle in {0,\AngleSep,..., 360} {%
        \draw [gray, ultra thick] (\Angle:#2) -- (\Angle:#1);
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\MidPoint}{\Angle+\AngleSep/2}
        \node at (\MidPoint:\MidRadius) {\GetListMember{#3}{\Count}};
    }%
}%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \CircularSequence{3.0cm}{2.cm}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=7.0cm]
        \CircularSequence{2.5cm}{1.5cm}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! (and fast) Sadly, this doesn't compile for me. The errors are:

`./circular-sequence-test.tex:26: Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessiblel.26 ...ularSequence{3.0cm}{2.cm}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
                                                  
    ? ./circular-sequence-test.tex:26: Undefined control     sequence.
    <argument> \Angle 
                      :2.cm
    l.26 ...ularSequence{3.0cm}{2.cm}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}` ... Replacing 2.cm with 2.0cm does not help.

Comment: I suspect that you are on an older release. Unless there is a good reason to stay on that you should probably to upgrade to TexLive 2012.

Comment: Indeed I am. I shall upgrade.

Comment: @Harold [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: @Harold: My crystal ball says that you are on a 2009 release. :-)  And if so, you should just install TeXLive2012 directly.

Comment: @PeterGrill 2010 ;)

Comment: @Harold: Yes you can instal both and switch. I have 2010, 2011 and 2012 all ready in case they are needed. Have really only used to determine if there is a bug in a new package - surprisingly quite rare.

Comment: The torrent was also fast! I'm up and running now. Thanks @PeterGrill.