# Irregular Polygon with Angle Labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

I am looking to create the 15-sided irregular polygon figure below, without having to declare coordinates for each point.

[image: 15-sided Irregular Polygon with angles]

Is there an easier way to do this? Tikz? PGF?

Comment: Are those angles random or fixed?

Comment: Perhaps this answer will get you started: [Circular sequence diagram (tikz?)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85726/circular-sequence-diagram-tikz).  Just connect the endpoints, and don't draw the circle.

Comment: Are the lengths of all segments identical?

Comment: Starting point can be something like

\draw (90:3)
\foreach \x in {0, 80, 185, 200, 270} {
 -- (90+\x:3) node [anchor=\x] {\x}
} -- cycle;

Comment: How is this figure built? What do the angles mean? How long are the segments? I suggest TikZ’ `turtle` library (maybe with some adjustments).

Comment: You guys work fast. The point of the picture is to demonstrate the "interior angle sum theorem." Here, a 15-sided polygon, has an angle sum of 2700 degrees. It seems @Jake 's answer will be the most appropriate. I will confirm shortly.

Comment: @Calhistorian According to [the English Wikipedia pages about Polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Angles) a 15-sided polygon has an angle sum of `180 (15 - 2) = 2340` degrees. Besides that, doesn’t have such a polygon more than one solution if all sides do not have the same length?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: There are infinitely many polygons with the same interior angles if the side lengths aren't fixed, but the angle sum will always be the same (just like the sum of the interior angles of a triangle is always 180, but there are infinitely many different triangles).

Comment: Whoops, yep your right. That's what I get for paying attention to other's annotations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a way to draw this polygon from a list of interior angles. The key points are the `\pgfextra{...}` command, which allows you to execute code without interrupting the path construction, and the `\path` commands with the `name path` keywords within the `pgfinterruptboundingbox` environment, which are used to find the final corner.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\totalangle{0}
\draw (0,0) -- (0:1cm) \foreach \angle in {152,165,167,160,160,150,150,150,170,145,170,155,170,155}{ 
    \pgfextra{  % Calculate the current direction
        \pgfmathparse{180-\angle+\totalangle}
        \xdef\totalangle{\pgfmathresult}
    }
 -- ++(\totalangle:1cm) node [pos=0, circle, anchor=(\totalangle+\angle/2+180), inner sep=0pt] {$\angle^\circ$}
} coordinate (final);

\pgfmathsetmacro\unknownangle{\totalangle-180}

% The final point is on the intersection between the extensions of the first and last segments.
% Interrupt the bounding box, so we can use long paths for finding the intersection.
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \path [name path global=horizontal] (-20cm,0pt) -- (20cm,0pt);
    \path [name path global=lastsegment] (final) -- +(\totalangle:30cm);
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

\draw [name intersections={of=horizontal and lastsegment}]
    (final) -- (intersection-1)
    node [anchor=south west] {$x$}
    -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I don't desire to actually calculate the unknown angle (x), how much of the code is necessary?  I don't have much experience with `pgf`.

Comment: The calculation of the angle is only one line `\pgfmathsetmacro\unknownangle{\totalangle-180}`. The entire second half of the code (from `\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}`) is only necessary because we don't know the length of the individual segments, so if you would precalculate that, the code could be shortened.

Comment: Ok. One last thing to confirm answer. Is it possible to add the degree symbol also to all the angles? I imagine this isn't that simple to do.

Comment: @Calhistorian: Sure, just replace `node ... {\angle}` `node ... {$\angle^\circ$}`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Ok, I know I said I was finished, but I shrunk the image by half (by modifying the `2cm` to `1cm`) which subsequently made the angle labels to be too far from the edge. I messed with some things, but can't get the label closer to the edge.

Comment: @Calhistorian: In that case, you need to decrease the `inner sep` of the label nodes (or set it to `0pt`). I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an adaptation of [Circular sequence diagram (tikz?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85726/circular-sequence-diagram-tikz) which will adapt to *any* number of segments based on the number of labels provided.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21559/macro-to-access-a-specific-member-of-a-list/21560#21560
\newcommand*\GetListMember[2]{\StrBetween[#2,\number\numexpr#2+1]{,#1,},,\par}%

\newlength{\MidRadius}
\newcommand{\LastAngle}{}%
\newcommand*{\CircularSequence}[3]{%
    % #1 = outer circle radius
    % #2 = inner circle radius
    % #3 = seqeunce
    \StrCount{#3}{,}[\NumberOfElements]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\AngleSep}{360/(\NumberOfElements+1)}
    \pgfmathsetlength{\MidRadius}{(#1+#2)/2}
    \foreach [count = \Count] \Angle in {0,\AngleSep,..., 360} {%
        \IfStrEq{\LastAngle}{}{}{%
            \draw [blue, ultra thick] (\LastAngle:#1) -- (\Angle:#1);
        }%
        \xdef\LastAngle{\Angle}% Save it so we can access it next iteration
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\MidPoint}{\Angle+\AngleSep/2}
        \node at (\MidPoint:\MidRadius) {\GetListMember{#3}{\Count}};
    }%
}%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \CircularSequence{4.0cm}{3.0cm}{170,155,170,165,$x$,163,155,167,170,160,140,150,172,170,145}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought the OP wanted the *irregular* polygon with the corner angles given by the labels.

Comment: @Jake: Good point, it is not really clear as the OP desires to _not_ specify the points of each of the coordinates.  Also, note that the labels are _not_ in order, so even more confusing.